# Problems with formatting XML files, with tags that have many attributes

Tags: xml, vim

I've been using vim daily for a year at home and at work. I recently started using a framework that makes intensive use of xml files (he uses it for his views). my problem is in the formatting of these files, especially when the element has many attributes and I have to go to the new line.
For example, button tag:

```xml
...
     ¦   ¦   <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_button_box']" position="inside">
     ¦   ¦   ¦   <button name="view_lpi_partner" type="object" string="Partner"
     ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-file-text"
     ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   attrs="{'invisible':[('need_partner', '=', False)]}">
     ¦   ¦   ¦   </button>
     ¦   ¦   </xpath>
...
```

If I try to format with `gg = G` I see that the next element, always the same parent, arrives at the top of the screen, not respecting its position within the same attribute.

I tried to use various plugins, but nothing most of them do not respect the lines of the numerous parameters of a element.

I also tried this script, modifying it when I could:

```
function! DoPrettyXML()
  " save the filetype so we can restore it later
  let l:origft = &ft
  set ft=
  " delete the xml header if it exists. This will
  " permit us to surround the document with fake tags
  " without creating invalid xml.
  1s/<?xml .*?>//e
  " insert fake tags around the entire document.
  " This will permit us to pretty-format excerpts of
  " XML that may contain multiple top-level elements.
  0put ='<PrettyXML>'
  $put ='</PrettyXML>'
  silent %!xmllint --format -
  " xmllint will insert an <?xml?> header. it's easy enough to delete
  " if you don't want it.
  " delete the fake tags
  2d
  $d
  " restore the 'normal' indentation, which is one extra level
  " too deep due to the extra tags we wrapped around the document.
  silent %<
  " back to home
  1
  " restore the filetype
  exe "set ft=" . l:origft
endfunction
command! PrettyXML call DoPrettyXML()
```

But without the desired result. Correct formatting is done by other editors / IDEs such as vs code and sublime text.

Can you tell me how to properly format an xml, even if the element's attributes are on a new line

Comment: They are not tags and parameters, they are elements and attributes. Searching for information on the internet is much easier if you use the correct terminology. Also, there is no such thing as a "correct" or "proper" format. There are many different ways of formatting this XML that are all correct, though some may be more aesthetically pleasing than others.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay and sorry for the wrong terminology, update immediately.